# Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList<Long?> but MutableCollection<Long> was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, collections, mutable

I'm attempting to create a MutableList using kotlin but I'm getting an error stating:

*Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is MutableList but MutableCollection was expected*

...and I'm not sure how to convert the MutableList to a MutableCollection.

I've tried using:

```
.toMutableList().toCollection()
```

but it's looking for a destination - and I'm not sure what to do.

**Code Snippet:**

```
data class HrmSearchResult(
    var rssi: Short?,
    var adjustRssi: Short?,
    var timeout: Int,
    var serialNumber: Long?,
    var isIn: Boolean,
    var countIn: Int
)

private val hashMapHrm = ConcurrentHashMap<Long?, HrmSearchResult>()

val hrmDeviceList: MutableCollection<Long>
    get() = try {
        if (hashMapHrm.elements().toList().none { it.isIn}) {
            //if there are no member in range, then return empty list
            arrayListOf()
        } else {
            hashMapHrm.elements()
                .toList()
                .filter { it.isIn }
                .sortedByDescending { it.adjustRssi }
                .map { it.serialNumber }
                .toMutableList().toCollection()
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        AppLog.e(
            LOG, "Problem when get devices " +
                    "return empty list: ${ex.localizedMessage}"
        )
        arrayListOf()
    }
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is the nullability, not the collection type, i.e. that you are creating a `List<Long?>` where a `List<Long>` is expected.

You can reproduce your error message (`inferred type is MutableList<Long?> but MutableCollection<Long> was expected`) minimally with this:

```
val foo: MutableCollection<Long> =
    listOf(1L, 2, 3, 4, null)
        .toMutableList()
```

And you can fix it by inserting `.filterNotNull()` to remove potential nulls, and convert a `List<T?>` to a `List<T>`:

```
val foo: MutableCollection<Long> =
    listOf(1L, 2, 3, 4, null)
        .filterNotNull()
        .toMutableList()
```

(So your `.toCollection()` call is actually not needed and can be dropped)

Some other notes specific to your code:

You probably want to use `.values` over `.elements.toList()`, and `map { }.filterNotNull()` can be combined into `mapNotNull`, so in summary, you probably want to write your chain as

```
hashMapHrm.values
    .filter { it.isIn }
    .sortedByDescending { it.adjustRssi }
    .mapNotNull { it.serialNumber }
    .toMutableList()
```